# Can one append to a make variable without overwriting what's set in the Makefile?

Tags: gnu-make

Let's consider the following Makefile:

```
.PHONY : all

OPTS += -DBLA
OPTS += -DBLUBB
STUFF = default

all :
    ./do_something $(OPTS) $(STUFF)
```

One can pass variables on the command line. So with the following call

```
confus@confusion:/tmp/$ make STUFF=foo
```

make will run `./do_something -DBLA -DBLUBB foo`.

Contrary to what I thought one can't append to variables:

```
confus@confusion:/tmp/$ make STUFF+=foo OPTS+=-DMOREOPT
```

will simply run `./do_something -DMOREOPT foo` (as if I had left out the plus signs), when I'd expect it to `./do_something -DBLA -DBLUBB -DMOREOPT default foo`.

Is there a way to append to a make variable with a command line option?

Comment: The variables are set *before* the script is running. So `make` is overwriting the values and not the other way around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is GNU make, you have to use the `override` directive in your makefile to specify that you want the values set in the makefile to take precedence over the command line values:

```
override OPTS += -DBLA
override OPTS += -DBLUBB
override STUFF += default
```

If it matters, note that this will put the settings provided on the command line first, and the settings in the makefile last.